# Calling an overloaded == operator in a different function that checks for !=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to write an operator `!=` function that compares if two complex numbers are the same. I Have written an equal to `==` function which works well but I am trying to use the negation of the result.

```
bool ComplexNumber::operator !=(ComplexNumber a) {
    return !(this==(a));  //the == has been overloaded
}
```

Comment: Unless this is homework (in which case a tag is missing), you can use [`std::complex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return !(this==(a));` is comparing a `ComplexNumber*` to a `ComplexNumber`. Change to:

```
bool ComplexNumber::operator !=(const ComplexNumber& a) const {
    return !(*this == a);  //the == has been overloaded
}
```

Also added `const` qualifier to function and argument (which I changed to to a reference to avoid unnecessary copy). You will need to add `const` qualifier to `bool ComplexNumber::operator ==()` if it is not already present.

Answer (score 3):

Please rewrite your post as a question.

I guess the question is: Why doesn't this work. The problem you have is that `this` is a pointer to an object, while `a` is an object.

```
bool ComplexNumber::operator !=(ComplexNumber a){
    return !(*this==(a));  //the == has been overloaded
}
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool ComplexNumber::operator !=(const ComplexNumber &a) const {
    return !operator==(a);
}
```

Comment: And what if `operator==()` was implemented as a free function ?

Comment: I'd also implement != as free then.

Comment: Using the `*this == a` form works in both situations and gives and similar result.